# Laravel Debugbar Affecting Excel Download

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, phpspreadsheet, phpdebugbar

So I installed Laravel Debugbar today in an attempt to make my local dev a better experience, and for the most part, it has. An issue has arisen though when I try to download an Excel generated from PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet (https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Here's a snippet of the code in question:

```php
$excelFile = new Spreadsheet();
// Load stuff from DB in Sheets, etc. etc.
$writer = new Xlsx($excelFile);
$filename = 'testing.xlsx';
$writer->save('php://output');
```

This works great, and the content is loaded into and downloaded as an `.xlsx` file without issue. When I open the file, I get this alert:

> We found a problem with some content in 'testing.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

I click "Yes", and then I get this alert:

> Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.

I click "Delete" and my file is opened, with nothing deleted (compared file against previous commit on `master` branch, no change).

Now here's the fun part, **I only get this alert when Debugbar is enabled**. In `.env`, I have `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true`, and if I set that to `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false` and reload/redownload, I don't get the alert. Has anyone seen this issue before? Why would Debugbar be messing with this? Is it an issue with `$writer->save('php://output');` being polluted by Debugbar's injection?

Sidenote, this will be a non-issue in `production`, as Debugbar is a `require-dev` dependence, but I'm just curious if I can avoid this during local development or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this has been asked and answered on the official documentation; was just a little tricky to find. I was correct about object pollution via debugbar, and the simply soultion was to add `exit();` after `$writer->save();`:

```php
$excelFile = new Spreadsheet();
// Load stuff from DB in Sheets, etc. etc.
$writer = new Xlsx($excelFile);
$filename = 'testing.xlsx';
$writer->save('php://output');
exit();
```

There were a couple more notes about `ob_clean()` and/or `ob_end_clean()`, `ob_flush()`, etc etc., but none of those worked with Laravel + Debugbar. For reference:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/217

Sidenote, this prevents Debugbar from handling the `GET` or `POST` request associated with the Excel download, so there's some give and take required. Simply commenting out the `exit()` locally will allow debugging, but the Excel will be marked as corrupt. Simple repeat action with `exit()` on will handle.